# 2x usb in one usb A connector?... Its just usb 3

Tags: usb

recently I bought a SATA to USB adapter and it did not work, so I opened it up to see if something was broken and I found that the USB cable had 9 wires.
When I looked at the USB connector I saw it had 9 "pins" instead of the 4 I had expected ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkSsp.jpg)).
What is this connector called? (so I can like buy an adapter)
I'm so so sorry, I did not know that it was just a USB 3 connector, though some other products that are advertised as SuperSpeed USB that I have that say (though I have not checked) that they can go at like 1 GB per second did not have the extra ones but those are probably just slower.

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. What kind of "a SATA to USB adapter" did you buy? What kind of drive did you connect to it? If you have a cable-looking adapter, and tried to use a desktop-kind of 3.5" HDD with it, it won't work for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a perfectly normal USB**3** connector. And they are supposed to have 9 pins.
The extra pins are only used by USB3, the normal 4 pins provide USB 1/2 compatibility.

Most likely your cable was just fine, but the USB to SATA converter chip inside the adapter needs drivers to work. Drivers that are not present in Windows as standard and that need to be installed manually.
(And be advised: Many of these adapters ONLY work if there is a SATA drive attached to it. Without a drive the adapter doesn't do anything at all and appears to be non-functional.)

Comment: Ah, well it said windows would natively support it but apparently not then (the last part is pretty obvious)

Comment: @adzwemer Natively supported... Maybe.. But by which Windows version? Windows 10 supports many of these, but there are 8 major versions of Windows 10 and the later ones support more than the earlier ones. Windows 7 and 8 support even less.

Comment: I'm using windows 10, I could just like have moved the hard drive to swiftly or the adapter cable I'm using is just broken (I don't know if the USB lead is providing enough power, it wants max 12 volts at 2 amps on startup and I found out that the chip in the cable is a VIA VI711S-04 (1527 D180658400) There is also another chip on the board)

Comment: I have purchased many adapters over the years and all of them work in XP thru W10 without extra drivers.

Comment: @adzwemer You'll probably need an external powersupply. USB isn't going to deliver that. Typically only 2.5" laptop drives are frugal enough that they can be fed through USB. And even then it is hit and miss depending on the USB controller on the motherboard.

Comment: @Moab Possible. If the USB-SATA converter presents itself as a generic USB mass-storage device to the OS it will work without needing drivers. But not all of them do. I must have seen at least 25 different models and brands of these over the years and in my experience about half of them didn't need drivers, the other half did.

Comment: @Tonny, if I would try to power it externally I'd need to cut up the little circuit board with the sata connector or supply more power through the usb lead but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @adzwemer If the USB-sata converter doesn’t provide the connector for an external psu your only option is a powered usb hub between pc and converter. Or get a better converter with its own psu.